# Помогите с задачей на си

Tags: c, строки

Нужно Разработать функцию HowMore(const S1,S2:string):integer, определяющую, на сколько
больше пробелов в строке S1, чем в S2. С помощью данной функции вывести только
такие строки из введенного набора, в которых пробелов по крайней мере на 3 больше,
чем в предыдущей строке. Количество строк может быть любое. Уже 3 дня убил на решение, не могу придумать.

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <conio.h>

int HowMore(char s1[], char s2[]) {
    int sum = 0, sum1 = 0;
    for (int i = 0; sizeof(s1)<sizeof(s2)?s2[i] != '\0':s1[i] != '\0';i++) {
        if (s1[i] == ' ') sum++;
        if (s2[i] == ' ') sum1++;
    }
    if (sum > sum1) return (sum - sum1);
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}

int main() {
    char s1[100], s2[100];
    int n;
    printf("Hi, please, enter the number of lines: ");
    scanf("%i", &n);
    for (int i=0; i <= n ; i++){
        gets(s1);
        printf("Enter next string: ");
        gets(s2);   
        if (HowMore(s2, s1) >= 3) puts(s2);
    
    }
    getchar();
}
```

Comment: `HowMore(const S1,S2:string):integer` — ну у вас же метка не Pascal...

Comment: Это просто задание с универа, нужно на си написать

Answer (score 2):

Я бы делал не совсем так...

```
int Spaces(const char *s)
{
    int count = 0;
    for(; *s; s++)
        if (*s == ' ') count++;
    return count;
}

int main()
{
    char s[2][100] = {0};
    int n, sp = 0;
    printf("Hi, please, enter the number of lines: ");
    scanf("%i", &n);
    for (int f = 0, i = 0; i <= n ; i++, f = 1 - f)
    {
        gets_s(s[f],100);
        int cur = Spaces(s[f]);
        if (cur - sp >= 3)
        {
            printf("Prev string \"%s\" has %d spaces\n",s[1-f],sp);
            printf("This string \"%s\" has %d spaces\n",s[f],cur);
        }
        sp = cur;
    }
}
```

Если позарез нужна `HowMore`, то

```
int HowMore(const char * s1, const char * s2) { return Spaces(s1) - Spaces(s2); }
```

P.S. `sizeof(s1)` вернет не то 4, не то 8 — размер *указателя* в вашей системе...

P.P.S. `i = 0; i <= n ;` — специально, для сброса лишнего `\n` из буфера после чтения `n`.

Comment: Обьясните. пожалуйста. как работает цикл, который находится в main

Comment: Обычный цикл для повторения n+1 раз действий в цикле. Переменная f поочередно имеет значение 0 и 1 — указывает, где лежит предыдущая строка, где последняя введенная (чтоб не плодить огромный массив — нам же нужны только 2 строки). Все. В теле цикла — сравнение количеств пробелов в текущей строке (cur) и предыдущей (sp). Если надо — вывод. Когда цикл заканчивается, текущая строка (и ее пробелы) становятся предыдущей.